# Adding new elements to List replaces the previous elements

Tags: java, list, arraylist

Getting wrong output
Here I have 3 List "chkptPrice","fuelNeeded" and "motherList". So in a loop I add new elements to "chkptPrice" and "fuelNeeded", then after that I add both the list to the "motherList". When the Loop run for the first time, everything goes fine but after that when I add new elements using "chkptPrice" and "fuelNeeded" to "motherList", the whole List is replaced by same elements and the elements are repeated.

```
System.out.println("Enter the test cases");
    int tess = scan.nextInt();
    scan.skip("(\r\n|[\n\r\u2028\u2029\u0085])?");
    System.out.println("Enter the number of checkpoints: ");
    int checkpt = scan.nextInt();
    scan.skip("(\r\n|[\n\r\u2028\u2029\u0085])?");
    List<List<Integer>> motherList = new ArrayList<List<Integer>>();
    List<Integer> chkptPrice = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    List<Integer> fuelNeeded = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    for(int i=0; i<tess; i++)
    {
        chkptPrice.clear();
        fuelNeeded.clear();
        String[] price = scan.nextLine().split(" ");
        for(int j=0; j<checkpt; j++)
        {
            int intPrice = Integer.parseInt(price[j]);
            chkptPrice.add(intPrice);
        }
        String[] fueldist = scan.nextLine().split(" ");
        for(int j=0; j<checkpt; j++)
        {
            int intDist = Integer.parseInt(fueldist[j]);
            fuelNeeded.add(intDist);
        }
        System.out.println("Elements in chktPrice: "+chkptPrice);
        System.out.println("Elements in fuelNeeded: "+fuelNeeded);

        motherList.add(chkptPrice);
        motherList.add(fuelNeeded);



        System.out.println("Elements of motherList: "+motherList);
    }
```

===== Input ======

```
    2
    2
    1 3
    4 6
    4 9
    1 8
```

===== Output ======

{1st Loop}

```
    Elements in chktPrice: [1, 3]
    Elements in fuelNeeded: [4, 6]
    Elements of motherList: [[1, 3], [4, 6]]
```

{2nd Loop}

```
    Elements in chktPrice: [4, 9]
    Elements in fuelNeeded: [1, 8]
    Elements of motherList: [[4, 9], [1, 8], [4, 9], [1, 8]]
```

motherList elements should be

> [[1, 3], [4, 6], [4, 9], [1, 8]]

Comment: Put your chkptPrice  and fuelNeeded list inside for loop. This will create new object while iteration.

Answer (score 3):

When you invoke `clear` you are not creating a new list but removing the contents of an already existing list (you empty the contents of the lists already added in the previous iterations).

Then, when you add them again to the motherList in the current iteration, you just add two new references pointing to the same old objects (so you end up with 4 references pointing to two objects).

To fix this, you would have to reinitialize the lists instead of using `clear`.

```
chkptPrice.clear(); -> chkptPrice = new LinkedList<>(); 
fuelNeeded.clear(); -> fuelNeeded = new LinkedList<>();
```

Comment: Thanks... It works... But can tell me more about what you said above about previous iteration and current iteration. And how 2 more referencing points are added with same elements. Or you can give me any source to get more info about it

Comment: The list does not store the objects themselves, but references to the actual objects.  Clear does not create new objects.

Comment: You can look for the differences between an object and a reference to an object

Comment: Thanks for explaining... previously I had no idea about it. If I want to delete the element directly from the object, how can I do.

Comment: Lists have a `remove` method that is used in order to remove an element from a list. Make sure you override `equals` so it works as expected. Note that removing an element from a list won't delete the element itself (i.e. if it is referenced somewhere else), will only delete List's reference to the object.